# How to delete a local git repository?

Tags: git

I run git status in a desktop's folder, then terminal shows something like:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .3T/
        .anaconda/
        .atom/
        .bash_history
        .cisco/
        .conda/
        .condarc
        .config/
        .dbshell
        ....
        Desktop/draft1.docx
        Desktop/pictures/
        Desktop/upload/
        ....
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        Links/
        ...
```

I am new to git, but it seems I created a git repository in my computer. What should I do? Delete this repository or something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to have a repository on your desktop, you should probably delete it.  One way to do this is to delete .git folder.  Note the folder is marked as hidden, so you will probably need to configure your windows option to show hidden folders.